# PHP reading files in a loop

Tags: php, loops, text, file-get-contents

Im having problems reading text files in a php loop. This is an easier example of my code and I know I should check to see it the file exists that is in my longer version but no matter what I do this won/t read my text files. The PHP warnings say that the text files are empty but they aren't. The PHP is writting the `<br />` tho.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
   $myFile = "$i.txt";
   $readfile = file_get_contents($myfile);
   echo "$readfile <br />";
}
```

Comment: You're reading the file `$myfile`, but you want to read `$myFile`, i.e. "undefined variable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your passing `$myfile` in `file_get_contents` but it's called `$myFile` above (case sensitive)

Answer (score 2):

Variables are case-sensitive.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $myFile = "$i.txt";
    $readfile = file_get_contents($myFile);
    echo "$readfile<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify your code, there are less chances to make an error:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
{
   readfile("$i.txt");
   echo "<br />";
}
```